# How to make First layout horizontal scroll only?

Tags: java, android, scrollview

I am having 2 Linear layout in 3 parents layout. Now they are synchronize when I scroll them in Vertical and Horizontal. How to disable the Vertical Scroll on First Layout but the horizontal scroll for both linear layout still **SYNCHRONIZED**?

```
<ScrollView>
    <HorizontalScrollView>

        <RelativeLayout>
            <LinearLayout>  --
                             |--First layout horizontal scrollable only
            </LinearLayout> --

            <LinearLayout>  --
                             |--Second layout both scrollable
            </LinearLayout> --
        <RelativeLayout>

    <HorizontalScrollView>
<ScrollView>
```

The following is the function that used to sync with the scroll view, not sure it helps or not

```
public void setListViewHeightBasedOnChildren(ListView listView) {
        ListAdapter listAdapter = listView.getAdapter();
        if (listAdapter == null)
            return;

        int desiredWidth = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(listView.getWidth(), View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
        int totalHeight = 0;
        View view = null;
        for (int i = 0; i < listAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
            view = listAdapter.getView(i, view, listView);
            if (i == 0)
                view.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(desiredWidth, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

            view.measure(desiredWidth, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
            totalHeight += view.getMeasuredHeight();
        }
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = listView.getLayoutParams();
        params.height = totalHeight + (listView.getDividerHeight() * (listAdapter.getCount() - 1));
        listView.setLayoutParams(params);
    }
```

Function call():

```
setListViewHeightBasedOnChildren(FirstLayout);
```

Really need help!!! Thanks!

Comment: did you try viewpager?

Comment: viewpager? sorry but any example on how to use it?

Comment: http://www.journaldev.com/10096/android-viewpager-example-tutorial

Comment: erm... viewpager seems like the changes of few pages, but what I want is scrolling on the same page instead of swiping, can viewpager solve my problem?

Comment: Then use recyclerview. with horizontal scroling

Comment: Check below solution that will help you scroll within scroll horizontal and vertical scrolling
http://code2care.org/pages/make-android-view-scrollable-both-horizontally-and-vertically/
or
https://androiddesk.wordpress.com/2011/12/16/horizontal-and-vertical-scrolling-in-android/

Comment: lol thanks guys, Im juz adjust the layout sequence then it works d!